# Cross compiling with linker scripts containing absolute paths

Tags: linker, cross-compiling

I am trying to do a cross compile making use of gcc's -sysroot option. However, when attempting to link against a linker script (libpthread.so or libc.so in particular), I get

```
$CTC_PATH/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/libc.so.6 when searching for /lib/libc.so.6
$CTC_PATH/bin/ld: cannot find /lib/libc.so.6
```

Basically the loader scripts contain absolute paths, and now it is trying to link against my host system's libraries located at those paths. I have worked around the problem by removing the absolute paths.

Does anyone know of another fix to this problem that doesn't involve editing the linker scripts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to convince GCC to do so, but the linker's prefix can be overriden by the  --rlink-path /path/to/prefix option.

I assume there is some gcc param to pass params to ld.

Comment: -Wloption,option passes options to the linker